# Как использовать одну функцию в разных моделях

Tags: laravel

Есть класс `Test` со статичной функцией `pars`

```
class Test
{
    public static function pars($modal) {
        $modal->create(['test' => 1]);
    }
}
```

Данную функцию мне нужно вызывать из других классов

Например

```
class Image extends Model
{
    public function parsImage() {
        $modal = new Image();
        Test::pars($modal)
    }
}
```

Данная запись работает и в функции `pars` можно работать с моделью `Image` но на сколько данная запись корректна?

Comment: корректна с точки зрения его? синтаксиса - вполне, проектирования - дело субъективое.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру С точки зрения синтаксиса, что я сначала создаю экземпляр класса, передаю его через параметр в функцию, а потом в этой функции с ним работаю

Comment: Да, это нормальная практика. В ооп все так делают, создвют объект и передают его в всякие места.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Понял, спасибо за ответ